# VueJS dynamic property name not updating value

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I am trying to implement an associated array combined with accessing the property within the value, the key is based on the value of the campaign object.

```
<li v-for="campaign in campaigns">
    <input type="text" v-model="configuration[campaign._id].value"> {{ configuration[campaign._id].value }}
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4yc3bujt/1/

Am I missing anything, it feels really bugged out. About exactly the same happens when trying to do this in VueJS 1, both times it's not throwing any errors.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is happening due to [caveats of reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) in `vue.js`. You have just defined     `configuration: {}` initially in data, so `configuration[key]` are not reactive. To make these reactive, you have to use [this.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set):

> Set a property on an object. If the object is reactive, ensure the property is created as a reactive property and trigger view updates. This is primarily used to get around the limitation that Vue cannot detect property additions.

use like following:

```
this.campaigns.forEach((campaign) => {
  var id = campaign._id;
  this.$set(this.configuration, id, {'value': 'default value'})
})
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    campaigns: [],
    configuration: {}
  },

  mounted: function() {
    this.campaigns = [{
      _id: 'abcdefg'
    }, {
      _id: 'kejwkfe'
    }, {
      _id: 'iruwiwe'
    }, {
      _id: 'reiwehb'
    }];

    this.campaigns.forEach((campaign) => {
      var id = campaign._id;
      this.$set(this.configuration, id, {'value': 'default value'})
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="campaign in campaigns">
      <input type="text" v-model="configuration[campaign._id].value" /> 
           {{ configuration[campaign._id].value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved it, thanks for pointing out the reactivity part!

Comment: Note that there is the opposite too : `this.$delete()` : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete

Answer (score 2):

Properties with reactivity must be in a Vue instance which is created by Vue constructor.

It ensures that properties are reactive and trigger view updates, i.e., they are initialed with `Object.defineProperty` and `MutationObserver` underlyingly.

So, use `Vue.set` to add new properties, and delete by `Vue.delete`.

View more info - [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)